# Is ‘there’ being treated as an object (noun)?

Tags: adverbs, direct-objects

The word "there" in this sentence doesn't seem to be necessary. But if it *is* there, what exactly is it? A noun? An adverb?

[See *there* where the willow bends over the brook.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22see%20there%20where%20the%22%20grow&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22see%20there%20where%20the%20willow%22&oq=%22see%20there%20where%20the%20willow%22&gs_l=serp.3...7729.11995.0.12381.12.12.0.0.0.0.143.799.11j1.12.0...0.0...1c.1.jhF3kRqljY8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=cd2c56685dba42a2&bpcl=38093640&biw=1223&bih=846)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, 'there' can be used as a noun (or arguably a pronoun) to refer to a *location* as a subject or object.

> See *there* where the willow bends over the brook.

*There* is still a noun, and the direct object, in this sentence.  The way you tell is, you can insert a comma:

> *See there*, where the willow bends over the brook.

This is still correct, so "See there" must be the main clause of the sentence; *where* is acting as a subordinating conjunction rather than an adverb, and it's fine in English to use a subordinate clause to modify the direct object.  A further check is to delete the clause:

> See there.

Telegraphic perhaps, definitely requires context to make *sense*, but still a valid sentence.

Addendum: You *can't* say

> *See there[,] *which* the willow bends over the brook.

because *there* **requires** *where* in this context.  It is the same phenomenon as not being able to use *which* or *that* to refer to people:

> *See the crowd, *which* are watching the stage.
>   See the crowd, *who* are watching the stage.

Soapbox: This seems to be yet another situation where schoolbook grammars mislead by trying to bend English to fit an analytic paradigm designed for Latin.  *Most* words in English can play the role of at least two parts of speech (for instance, as a wise man once said, [nearly] all nouns can be verbed).  In particular it might be analytically cleaner to merge the categories "adjective" and "adverb" and reconstrue the *-ly* suffix as an agreement marker rather than a derivation operator.

Comment: While the argument about a cromulent reference is fine, in this case *there* is certainly not a noun -- as the presence of *where*, not *which*, shows. However, you did not quite say what pos it is.

Comment: @Kris: OED's primary definition is *I - As a demonstrative **adverb***, but it does eventually get to *III.11 as **noun**. That place; the (or a) place yonder.* That seems credible to me here (in *this* place, so to speak! :)

Comment: @Zack: I changed OP's example because it was a bit "weird", but structurally it's the same thing. Sorry it messes up some of your references to the text - I don't think it invalidates your basic point, but maybe you might want to edit a bit.

Comment: @Kris. Please explain how the presence of where proves that "there" is not a noun. So in "the place where I live", "the place" is not a noun?

Comment: @FumbleFingers yeah, that's a better example.  Expanded on my point quite a bit.

Comment: @Kris 'Where' can be used to modify things that are playing the role of a noun.  See edit.

Comment: But you may also put a comma **before** *there*. I suggest that a more natural reading would be to take the imperative *see* in an intransitive sense and *there* as an adverb -- "Look in that direction!" rather than "Behold that place!"

Comment: @StoneyB: The original question was rather oddly phrased, but I think my edit reflected what OP was really asking about. Which in the end seems to be quite a fine point. So far as I can make out, you could classify *"there"* here as either adverb or noun, depending on how you want to look at it. Me, I think Zack's final "soapbox" paragraph is very apposite.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yah, I agree with just about everything except the main point, which is how *there* is being used *in this instance*.

Comment: **There** here really does say something more about the action of the verb. This argues for it being an adverb (here). However, locatives and directionals are notoriously difficult to lock up in fixed word-classes (it is even difficult to consider that they spend time in **various** traditional classes). In _He came home_, home might be considered an adverb 'modifying' the 'coming process' - ie telling us _where_ he came. In _Is he home?_ there is less compulsion to regard home as an adverb - _be_ doesn't accept adverbs gladly. Perhaps it's best to put these locatives in their own class.

Comment: @Edwin: Precisely. The mere fact that you can say *perhaps it's best to put these locatives in their own class* strongly implies that Zack's right when he says we're trying to force things into a paradigm that doesn't really reflect English very well in this area.